# can't get popupwindow and no response in a Netbeans project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

I am modifying my Java program's GUI. Once I got the GUI design done, and imported the Netbeans project into Eclipse, I found that when a popup window (for example, an error message) should occur, the program does not respond at all, but other functionalities work fine.

Why is this happening? The project directory contains both files required for either Netbeans or Eclipse, this original directory used to work on a Mac. I imported it into Nebteans on Windows and resized components of the GUI because the looks of my GUI on Windows is completely different, and I have no idea about Swing "looks and feels".

I was wondering if files in project directory were modified or inappropriate when I did import from Netbeans to Eclipse. If someone can give me any help, it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: *"Why is this happening?"* I suspect it is either a) the code, or b) the resource structure of the project (is different between IDEs).  Note that I can offer no more than suspicions based on the lack of information, and am amazed anyone thought this was a 'good question' (that it 'shows research effort & is useful & clear').